# Can I change the steam controller's sticks?

Tags: hardware, controllers

I recently bought a steam controller and really love it. One problem is I really don't like its stick, and would like to change it.

I own an XBox controller annd know I love those sticks, is there any chance I could switch the two ? If so, are there guides / explanations available on the web ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it is possible, though it appears to be tricky. I found a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf7eKATqMvw) describing how somebody modded their steam controller using an Xbox-one style joystick.

However, be careful - it looks like the process of modding the steam controller joystick using Xbox or PlayStation joysticks [can be difficult](https://www.reddit.com/r/SteamControllerMods/comments/3yho9w/attempt_to_use_xbox_one_joystick_failed_they_dont/) without the proper tools and experience, especially when it comes to modifying the joystick itself (which WILL NOT fit onto the controller without some modification - the video above recommends using a drill press to make the joystick fit onto the controller, whereas the Reddit thread recommends using a dremel).

Should you decide to proceed, [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Steam+Controller+Teardown/52578) is a tutorial for how to take apart the controller in more detail than the video above. Good luck, and happy modding!